# How to EMIT (Socket IO) on CRUD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

How can i call **socket.broadcast.emit()** on my **CRUD**?

I want to **emit** an event from my socket after performing the **CRUD** but I can't emit the event on **userController.js**

**index.js** and **sockets.js** is on the same level

[image]

**INDEX.JS**

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import http from 'node:http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import { socketController } from './sockets.js'

/* DOTENV */
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' })

/* ARCHIVOS DEDICADOS PARA LAS RUTAS */
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js'

/* CREAR APP */
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {cors: { origin: 'http://localhost:5173'}})

/* CONEXION SOCKET CLIENTE */
io.on('connection', socketController)

/* HABILITANDO RECIBIR DATA DESDE EL BODY */
app.use( express.urlencoded({ extended:true }) )

/* RUTAS */
app.use('/user', userRoutes)

/* ESCUCHANDO/CORRIENDO SERVIDOR */
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030
server.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Corriendo en el puerto: ${port}`)
})
```

**SOCKET.JS**

```
const socketController = (socket) => {
  console.log('Client Connect: ' + socket.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('CLlient Disconnect: ' + socket.id);
  })
  /* REACCIONANDO AL EVENTO Y RECIBIENDO EL PAYLOAD Y UN CALLBACK */
  socket.on('send-message', (payload, callback) => {

    /* EJECUTANDO EL CALLBACK RECIBIDO - ADICIONAL REENVIO EL PAYLOAD ORIGINAL */
    callback(payload)
    
    /* EMITIENDO EL EVENTO SHOW-MESSAGE Y ENVIANDO EL PAYLOAD */
    socket.broadcast.emit('show-message', payload)
  })
}

export { socketController }
```

**userController.js**

```
const createUser = async (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body

  res
    .status(201)
    .json({
      ok: true,
      message: body.message,
    })
}

const readUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({
      ok: true,
      message: 'User found',
      user: id
    })
}

const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const body = req.body

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({
      ok: true,
      message: 'User updated succesfully',
      userUpdated: body, id
    })
}

const deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({
      ok: true,
      message: 'User deleted successfully',
      userDeleted: id
    })
}

const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({
      ok: true,
      message: 'Showing All Users',
      users: 'Hello'
    })
}

export { createUser, readUser, updateUser, deleteUser, getAllUsers }
```

As you can see its my very first time working with Socket.io and i just run an app for send data to the server and catch viceversa, justo to understand the flow of the data.

On my intention is build a crud and  after every request make an emit to the socket and the socket will update on the web app, but the web app its no the problem here

I justo know how to send that emit from the userController, because it was the structure i will use for my REST APIS

Sorry for the bad english, imi not a native speaker and newbie on sockets techonologie